# .exists() method always returns false

Tags: java, file-io

In the below code, I am checking if a file exists in a specific path using the method `isExist()`. The problem is this method always returns false no matter the file exists or not.

Kindly please have a look at the code posted below, and let me know what I am missing.
**Code**:

```
    if (isExist(SYS_CONFIG_PATH, SYS_CONFIG_FILE)) {
                System.out.println("@SystemConfig->getInstance(): System Configuration File " + SYS_CONFIG_FILE + " exists.");
                return new File(SYS_CONFIG_PATH + "\\" + SYS_CONFIG_FILE);
            }else {
                System.out.println("@SystemConfig->getInstance(): System Configuration File " + SYS_CONFIG_FILE + " is not existing, will be created.");
                return buildPathAt(SYS_CONFIG_PATH);
     ....
     ....

     private static boolean isExist(String path1, String path2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String path = path1 + path2;
    return new File(path.trim()).exists();
}
```

Comment: Using + with Paths looks so fragile (and error-prone). You can't use Paths.get(). What is the logic between path1 and path2? Should path2 be inside path1? Debug the path.trim() value too.

Answer (score 2):

It simply looks like **SYS_CONFIG_PATH**, **SYS_CONFIG_FILE** are over lapping into something like...

> C:/user/temp + C:/user/temp/myfile.txt =
>   C:/user/tempC:/user/temp/myfile.text

`System.out` these **SYS_CONFIG_PATH**, **SYS_CONFIG_FILE**

You might be able to see the problem there.